# get number of parametres in python function

Tags: python, function, testing

I make function, to get number of params in function, but it gives number only if they are given, but the find that I really need is to get number just by getting func name.

```
def a(a, b, c):
    par = len(locals())
    return par

z = a()
```

I need to get z equal to 3, but it gives mistake.

```
def a(a, b, c):
    par = len(locals())
    return par

z = a(1, 2, 3)
```

I need opportunity to get len without giving params.

Answer (score 3):

Python allows your function to accept an [arbitrary number of positional arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) by using [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
def a(*args):  # allows any number of arguments without runtime errors
    par = len(args)  # args is a tuple of all the provided arguments
    return par

a(1, 2, 3)
# 3
a()
# 0
```